# How does FCKeditor or TinyMCE capture pasted images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, fckeditor

I would like to be able to display pasted images by the user on the client side.

I would like to do it in a similar manner to FCKeditor/TinyMCE, not using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor: (only in firefox)
http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=23646

In Gmail, when you paste an image it looks like this:

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAyAQMAAACnNSPJAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAXRSTlOArV5bRgAAABhJREFUeF6VwQENAAAAgjCjG50GbPwzDwUmggsB4+yamQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" _moz_dirty="">
```

But, I think if you want this to work on all browsers, it might not be possible.

Comment: I think we should have some ways to encode the image to the binary string